# I haven't been able to parse '2017-04-04T08:04+0000' into an OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-formatting, dateformatter, isodate

I have created this deserializer to be managed in a centralized custom object mapper bean, and it works fine, but I'm not able to deserialize the dates that are coming in this format '2017-04-04T08:04+0000' into the correct OffsetDateTime format - getting the following exception:

```
Text '2017-04-04T08:04+0000' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19 (through reference chain: earth.green.integration_models.sh.Prediction$PredictionBuilder["created"])
```

I have searched lots of formats on the internet and none of them have worked, so if any of you know which format can I use to deserialize this date, will be very helpful.

```
public class OffsetDateTimeDeserializer
      extends JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime>
{
    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm[XXX][XXXX]" );


    @Override
    public OffsetDateTime deserialize( final JsonParser parser,
                                       final DeserializationContext context )
          throws IOException
    {
        formatter.withZone( ZoneId.of( "GMT") );
        return OffsetDateTime.parse( parser.readValueAs( String.class ), formatter );
    }
}
```

Comment: You created a date formatter with a custom format, but then you end up not using it. Use `formatter` instead of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.

Comment: Use format `"uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX"`

Comment: Thanks, @Andreas I think your format worked, also I tried this one by playing with the 'X's "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm[XXXXX][XXXX][X]" which also worked

Comment: I could not reproduce. On both my Java 8 and my Java 11 your formatter parses `2017-04-04T08:04+0000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just two lower case xx for offset without colon

```
private final DateTimeFormatter formatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mmxx" );
```

When offset zero is given as `+0000` rather than `Z`, use lower case `xx`.

Demonstration:

```
    String valueAsString = "2017-04-04T08:04+0000";
    OffsetDateTime deserialized = OffsetDateTime.parse( valueAsString, formatter );
    System.out.println( deserialized );
```

This outputs:

> 2017-04-04T08:04Z

**What went wrong in your code?** From the documentation:

> **Offset X and x:** This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01',
> unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output,
> such as '+0130'. Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a
> colon, such as '+0130'. Three letters outputs the hour and minute,
> with a colon, such as '+01:30'. Four letters outputs the hour and
> minute and optional second, without a colon, such as '+013015'. Five
> letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon,
> such as '+01:30:15'. …

According to this `XXX` should try to parse an offset like `+00:00`, with a colon, and fail since there is no colon in the offset in the parsed string. Next `XXXX` should try either `+0000` or `+000000` since the seconds are optional, so should succeed. Which it also did on my computer. So explanations I can think of include:

- The code you were running was not eaxctly the same code as you posted in the question. I believe that maybe the first version of your question contained the code that produced the exception, and you haven’t updated the exception message after updating the code.
- (Possibly your Java version had a bug where three `XXX` parsed just `+00` (the hours) and left the final `00` unparsed, after which `XXXX` couldn’t do anything. It’s not a bug I’ve heard of, so pure speculation and not really likely. If this were the problem, just swapping `[XXX]` and `[XXXX]` should remedy it.)

**Edit: Do you know what can I want to get it deserialized in the same format as the string, just to serialize back and compare the two strings and look that they are equal?**

1. Do that test the other way around: Serialize an `OffsetDateTime`, deserialize it back and check that the two `OffsetDateTime` objects are equal.
2. If you insist, use lower case `xx` in the format pattern string. This prevents offset zero being rendered as `Z`. Meaning that `2017-04-04T08:04+0000` will be printed back, the same string as you started out from.